# Fail the Jenkins build if there is test failures in a multi-module Maven Project

Tags: maven, jenkins, multi-module

At the moment I have a project, lets call it `mightymouse`. Mightymouse POM is a multi-module project for `mightymouse-web` and `mightmouse-backend`.

Both of the sub modules have tests. In my situation, the `mightymouse-web` project compiles, test, package, install, deploys first. Then then `-backend` project goes through, only to fail during the `integration-test` stage. (Yet, it still goes through to the `deploy` stage).

The Jenkins job is setup to execute `mvn clean deploy`.

**Question**: Is there anyway to prevent Maven from going all the way to the `deploy` step on any module failing it's tests?

Comment: You run `mvn clean deploy` on your aggregator `mightymouse`, right? If so I wonder why `web` is built first? Doesn't `web`  use dependencies from `backend`? Can we see some relevant parts of the POMs and the build output?

Comment: it was just an example lets say for this case backend depends on web.

Comment: Does that mean that this is not a real problem? A question just in case...?

Answer (score 2):

By default, a maven multi module build also uses the [`fail-fast` option](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

> `--fail-fast` - the default behavior - whenever a module build fails, stop the overall build immediately

Moreover, by default the [`maven-failsafe-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin) already fails as soon as an integration test fails via the [`testFailureIgnore`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) option

> Set this to `true` to ignore a failure during testing. Its use is NOT RECOMMENDED, but quite convenient on occasion.
>   **User Property**: `maven.test.failure.ignore`
>   **Default**: `false`

Note that the [`maven-surefire-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin) has [the same](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) for unit testings.

Hence, by default a multi-module build should stop as soon as a test fails (unit test or integration test), no further module would be built and not further maven phase should be invoked.

However, a Maven Jenkins job (and not a freestyle Jenkins job invoking Maven) [set this option](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24655) to `true` by default and hence the build would not fail, it will keep on and deploy, while the job would be set to `UNSTABLE` and not `SUCCESSFUL` (but still deploying).

As such, you could change your maven invocation in your Jenkins job to:

```
mvn clean deploy -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false
```

Overriding thus Jenkins default settings and meeting your requirements.